# Include Cover Page in Tufte Style Book

Tags: tufte

I am trying to include a cover page in the [Tufte Style Book Template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/tufte-style-book) using the `\AddToShipoutPicture*` command.  I also included the following code:

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
\put(0,0){%
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,%
keepaspectratio]{background.png}%
\vfill
}}}
```

For some reason, the cover page remains small and I cannot seem to get it to appear any larger to cover the page.  Can you help me get the cover page to show up to fill the first page?

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book} % Use the tufte-book class which in turn uses the tufte-common class

\hypersetup{colorlinks} % Comment this line if you don't wish to have colored links

\usepackage{microtype} % Improves character and word spacing

\usepackage{lipsum} % Inserts dummy text

\usepackage{booktabs} % Better horizontal rules in tables

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % Needed to insert images into the document
\graphicspath{{graphics/}} % Sets the default location of pictures
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio} % Improves figure scaling

\usepackage{fancyvrb} % Allows customization of verbatim environments
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize} % The font size of all verbatim text can be changed here

\newcommand{\hangp}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{(}#1\makebox[0pt][l]{)}} % New command to create parentheses around text in tables which take up no horizontal space - this improves column spacing
\newcommand{\hangstar}{\makebox[0pt][l]{*}} % New command to create asterisks in tables which take up no horizontal space - this improves column spacing

\usepackage{xspace} % Used for printing a trailing space better than using a tilde (~) using the \xspace command

\newcommand{\monthyear}{\ifcase\month\or January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi\space\number\year} % A command to print the current month and year

\newcommand{\openepigraph}[2]{ % This block sets up a command for printing an epigraph with 2 arguments - the quote and the author
\begin{fullwidth}
\sffamily\large
\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\allcaps{#1}\\ % The quote
\noindent\allcaps{#2} % The author
\end{doublespace}
\end{fullwidth}
}

\newcommand{\blankpage}{\newpage\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage} % Command to insert a blank page

\usepackage{units} % Used for printing standard units

\newcommand{\hlred}[1]{\textcolor{Maroon}{#1}} % Print text in maroon
\newcommand{\hangleft}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{#1}} % Used for printing commands in the index, moves the slash left so the command name aligns with the rest of the text in the index
\newcommand{\hairsp}{\hspace{1pt}} % Command to print a very short space
\newcommand{\ie}{\textit{i.\hairsp{}e.}\xspace} % Command to print i.e.
\newcommand{\eg}{\textit{e.\hairsp{}g.}\xspace} % Command to print e.g.
\newcommand{\na}{\quad--} % Used in tables for N/A cells
\newcommand{\measure}[3]{#1/#2$\times$\unit[#3]{pc}} % Typesets the font size, leading, and measure in the form of: 10/12x26 pc.
\newcommand{\tuftebs}{\symbol{'134}} % Command to print a backslash in tt type in OT1/T1

\providecommand{\XeLaTeX}{X\lower.5ex\hbox{\kern-0.15em\reflectbox{E}}\kern-0.1em\LaTeX}
\newcommand{\tXeLaTeX}{\XeLaTeX\index{XeLaTeX@\protect\XeLaTeX}} % Command to print the XeLaTeX logo while simultaneously adding the position to the index

\newcommand{\doccmdnoindex}[2][]{\texttt{\tuftebs#2}} % Command to print a command in texttt with a backslash of tt type without inserting the command into the index

\newcommand{\doccmddef}[2][]{\hlred{\texttt{\tuftebs#2}}\label{cmd:#2}\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}} % Command to define a command in red and add it to the index
{ % If no package is specified, add the command to the index
\index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2}}% Command name
}
{ % If a package is also specified as a second argument, add the command and package to the index
\index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2} (\texttt{#1} package)}% Command name
\index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}% Package name
}}

\newcommand{\doccmd}[2][]{% Command to define a command and add it to the index
\texttt{\tuftebs#2}%
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}% If no package is specified, add the command to the index
{%
\index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2}}% Command name
}
{%
\index{#2 command@\protect\hangleft{\texttt{\tuftebs}}\texttt{#2} (\texttt{#1} package)}% Command name
\index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}% Package name
}}

% A bunch of new commands to print commands, arguments, environments, classes, etc within the text using the correct formatting
\newcommand{\docopt}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle}\textrm{\textit{#1}}\ensuremath{\rangle}}
\newcommand{\docarg}[1]{\textrm{\textit{#1}}}
\newenvironment{docspec}{\begin{quotation}\ttfamily\parskip0pt\parindent0pt\ignorespaces}{\end{quotation}}
\newcommand{\docenv}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 environment@\texttt{#1} environment}\index{environments!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\docenvdef}[1]{\hlred{\texttt{#1}}\label{env:#1}\index{#1 environment@\texttt{#1} environment}\index{environments!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\docpkg}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 package@\texttt{#1} package}\index{packages!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\doccls}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\docclsopt}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 class option@\texttt{#1} class option}\index{class options!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\docclsoptdef}[1]{\hlred{\texttt{#1}}\label{clsopt:#1}\index{#1 class option@\texttt{#1} class option}\index{class options!#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\docmsg}[2]{\bigskip\begin{fullwidth}\noindent\ttfamily#1\end{fullwidth}\medskip\par\noindent#2}
\newcommand{\docfilehook}[2]{\texttt{#1}\index{file hooks!#2}\index{#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\doccounter}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1 counter@\texttt{#1} counter}}

\usepackage{makeidx} % Used to generate the index
\makeindex % Generate the index which is printed at the end of the document

% This block contains a number of shortcuts used throughout the book
\newcommand{\vdqi}{\textit{VDQI}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ei}{\textit{EI}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ve}{\textit{VE}\xspace}
\newcommand{\be}{\textit{BE}\xspace}
\newcommand{\VDQI}{\textit{The Visual Display of Quantitative Information}\xspace}
\newcommand{\EI}{\textit{Envisioning Information}\xspace}
\newcommand{\VE}{\textit{Visual Explanations}\xspace}
\newcommand{\BE}{\textit{Beautiful Evidence}\xspace}
\newcommand{\TL}{Tufte-\LaTeX\xspace}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BOOK META-INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{A Tufte-Style Book\thanks{Thanks to Edward R.~Tufte for his inspiration.}} % Title of the book

\author[The Tufte-LaTeX Developers]{The Tufte-LaTeX\ Developers} % Author

\publisher{Publisher of This Book} % Publisher


\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
\put(0,0){%
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,%
keepaspectratio]{background.png}%
\vfill
}}}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\thispagestyle{empty}

\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(-3,-6.5){\includegraphics[scale=10]{cover}}} % Image background

\mbox{}

\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\openepigraph{The public is more familiar with bad design than good design. It is, in effect, conditioned to prefer bad design, because that is what it lives with. The new becomes threatening, the old reassuring.}{Paul Rand, {\itshape Design, Form, and Chaos}}
\vfill
\openepigraph{A designer knows that he has achieved perfection not when there is nothing left to add, but when there is nothing left to take away.}{Antoine de Saint-Exup\'{e}ry}
\vfill
\openepigraph{\ldots the designer of a new system must not only be the implementor and the first large-scale user; the designer should also write the first user manual\ldots If I had not participated fully in all these activities, literally hundreds of improvements would never have been made, because I would never have thought of them or perceived why they were important.}{Donald E. Knuth}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\maketitle % Print the title page

\newpage
\begin{fullwidth}
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
Copyright \copyright\ \the\year\ \thanklessauthor

\par\smallcaps{Published by \thanklesspublisher}

\par\smallcaps{tufte-latex.googlecode.com}

\par Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the ``License''); you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at \url{http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0}. Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an \smallcaps{``AS IS'' BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND}, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.\index{license}

\par\textit{First printing, \monthyear}
\end{fullwidth}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTRODUCTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Introduction} % The asterisk leaves out this chapter from the table of contents

This sample book discusses the design of Edward Tufte's books\cite{Tufte2001,Tufte1990,Tufte1997,Tufte2006} and the use of the \doccls{tufte-book} and \doccls{tufte-handout} document classes.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\mainmatter

\chapter{The Design of Tufte's Books}
\label{ch:tufte-design}

\newthought{The pages} of a book are usually divided into three major sections: the front matter (also called preliminary matter or prelim), the main matter (the core text of the book), and the back matter (or end matter).

\newthought{The front matter} of a book refers to all of the material that comes before the main text. The following table shows a list of material that appears in the front matter of \VDQI, \EI, \VE, and \BE along with its page number. Page numbers that appear in parentheses refer to folios that do not have a printed page number (but they are still counted in the page number sequence).

\end{document}
```

Comment: Create the cover completely independent from your real document, that you can include using a tool you want. Remember, the physical paper has to be slightly larger (and the background image as well), printers cannot print to the ery edge of paper.